# Query to add to current value?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

So I want to make a query to add to the current value. note that this is for MSSQL(Microsoft SQL) database not MySQL,
example of what i want it to do"

```
ID | value            ID | Value
-------------- after  ----------
1  | 1                 1 | 2
```

Basically I just want it to add to the current value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable
   SET Value = Value + 1
 WHERE ID = 1
```

You will need to provide more details if this isn't sufficient.